# Pass req variables from .param to .use?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

The code below demonstrates trying to log `req.hash_id` from middleware. It's showing up for me as `undefined`. Is there anyway that I can get this to work? Or easily parse ":hash" out in regular .use middleware?

```
app.param("hash",function(req, res, next, id){
  req.hash_id = id;
  return next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.hash_id);
  return next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `req.params` inside a middleware function as it is bound to specific routes. You could use `req.query` though, but then you have to write your routes differently, e.g. `/user?hash=12345abc`. Not sure about passing the value from `app.param` to `app.use`.

If you have a specific structure for your routes, like `/user/:hash` you could simply write

```
// that part is fine
app.param('hash',function(req, res, next, id){
  req.hash_id = id;
  return next();
});

app.all('/user/:hash', function(req, res, next) { // app.all instead app.use
  console.log(req.hash_id);
  next();  // continue to sending an answer or some html
});

// GET /user/steve -> steve
```

Comment: I want to use `app.use()` middleware to intercept the call between both `app.param()` and `app.all()` and utilize the `req.hash_id` variable. But it is `undefined` full example here: https://gist.github.com/4532510.

Comment: That's a bit tricky. `app.param` is part of the router. `req.hash_id` is `undefined` as the middleware is called BEFORE the `router`. Putting your `app.use` AFTER the `router` won't work as the router is the end of the middleware chain.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get how it all works now. I got rid of `app.param` and am parsing `req.url` for hash within `app.use` middleware.